# Spock Error while handling ["v1","graphql"]: InvalidUrlException "" "Invalid URL"

Tags: hasura, hasura-cli

I have Hasura Graphql v2.35 running in my server where suddenly the one of the insert mutation started throwing error `internal server error 500`

Very unusual of hasura to throw error which is not descriptive.

On inspecting the Hasura logs all i can see the

```
Spock Error while handling ["v1","graphql"]: InvalidUrlException "" "Invalid URL"
```

tried searching in forums and over a google but no luck.

What might be causing the Invalid URL where all other mutation and queries are working fine? and no new change except permission changes to this entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `input validation` is enabled and webhook URL is emtpy

[image: input validation example image]

This is what was causing the above issue where difficult to understand from the error message

```
Spock Error while handling ["v1","graphql"]: InvalidUrlException "" "Invalid URL"
```

And client side it was

```
Internal Server Error
```

Disabling the input validation definitely worked but, adding validation Webhook URL works as well

```
 validate_input:
    definition:
      forward_client_headers: false
      headers: []
      timeout: 10
      url: "http://webhook.url"
    type: http
```